# convert a number to decimal number without rounding

Tags: php

I have this number

```
$sku = '2200081005966';
```

and I want to convert the number like this without rounding the number

```
$new_sku = '5.96'
```

I already try this `number_format(substr($sku, 7, 12), 0, '', '.')`
but the output that I get `5.97`.

Any ideas how can I make this work?

Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a PHP question, not a Javascript question?

Comment: Yup, php question..my mistake

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I don't understand it correctly but what are the general rules of this conversion? Get substring from 7th character with decimal dot in the middle and cut after two decimal digits?

Comment: Just perform the truncation BEFORE formatting.  `var_export(number_format(substr($sku, 7, 11), 0, '', '.'));` ...or I don't understand your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [floor()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) around your `number_format`:

```
$sku = '2200081005966';
echo floor(number_format(substr($sku, 7, 12), 0, '', '.')*100)/100;
```

Outputs:

```
5.96
```

**Note:** *It would works well in case of positive numbers, your substr always take a positive number, that's why it would be enough.*

Comment: that's work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$sku = '2200081005966';
$foo=substr($sku, 9, 12);
echo substr($foo, 0,2).".".substr($foo, 3,3);
?>
```

first you get the last 4 charakters of the string, then you split that part and put a dot between.

Comment: OP uses **substr($sku, 7, 12)**. It won't work.

Comment: I see that - and I thought it was a mistake - my bad 
But I guess, there is more than one possible solution to this.