# Subtract string and convert to decimal without rounding

Tags: php

I have a number declaration

```
$barcode_scan = '220008100383005193';
```

and I want the output like this `0.519`.

I already try this code

```
number_format(substr($barcode_scan, -6), 0, '', '.');
```

but the output is `5.193`. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to take off the '2200081003830', what's the criteria?

Comment: This looks amazingly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58989475/convert-a-number-to-decimal-number-without-rounding) other question.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but is this what you want? https://3v4l.org/HLpqi

Comment: because the $barcode_scan is a barcode from a product. The last six of $barcode_scan actually is a weight of product. That's  why I want to take off the other number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58989475/convert-a-number-to-decimal-number-without-rounding).

In your case code should be next:

```
$barcode_scan = '220008100383005193';
echo floor(number_format(substr($barcode_scan, -6), 0, '', '.')*100)/1000;
```

[Outputs](https://3v4l.org/rSXNb):

```
0.519
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

number_format(substr($barcode_scan, -6)/10000, 3)

OR

number_format(substr($barcode_scan, -6)/10000, 3, '.', ',')

That is conflict of decimal point symbol and thousand separator symbol